# Nenegata versio de “ĉu ne?”

Tags: grammar

Estas “ĉu ne?” por fari demandon ĉu la aserto de ĉeffrazo estas neĝusta, ekzemple “Vi vidas tion, ĉu ne?”.

Kiel oni diras la malon? T.e. "Vi ne vidas tion, …"? (angla: ‘You don't see that, do you?‘ aŭ germana: „Du siehst es nicht, oder?”)

Mi pensas “ĉu?” aŭ “ĉu jes?”.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Ĉu?* estas malplena demando. Ĝi signifas *Ĉu vere?* aŭ *Ĉu mi pravas?* aŭ simple *Oh?*

> "Ĉu? Mi ĝojas! Mi ĵus estis vizitonta vian kontoron." (el *Metropoliteno*)

La aldono *...ĉu?* signifas *Ĉu mi pravas?* post aserto kun aŭ sen *ne*.

> "Do, vi estas spiono, sendita de la pastroj? Ĉu?" (el *Pro Iŝtar*)
>
> "Sed kiam homo juna, iam-tiam amoreti ne malutilas, ĉu?" (el *La skandalo pro Jozefo*)

La aldono *...ĉu ne?* estas ironia, bruska aŭ maltrankvila provoketo.

> "Vi havas la mapon, ĉu ne?"

Oni ankaŭ uzas *Ĉu jes?* kaj *Ĉu ne?* por esprimi dubon: *Ĉu mi malpravas?*

> "Vi ne faris la hejmtaskon. Ĉu jes?"
>
> "Kompreneble vi faris la hejmtaskon. Ĉu ne?"

Do, *Vi ne vidas tion, ĉu jes?* esprimas pli da dubo.

> *Vi ne vidas tion, ĉu?* You don't see that, right?
>
> *Vi ne vidas tion, ĉu jes?* You don't see that—or do you?

Comment: El tiu ĉi respondo mi aparte ŝatas la du lastajn frazojn... ĉar ili klarigas por mi duban punkton de la angla lingvo per esperantaj esprimoj por mi multe pli klaraj... tiu ĉi demandejo povas funkcii en pluraj direktoj...

Answer (score 0):

Ekzistas filozofia problemo kun tiaj demandoj en la fino de la frazo. Kelkaj homoj sentas tiujn kiel tro premaj, ke estus nur du absolutaj alternativoj: jes aŭ ne. Mi preferas, ke oni formas veran demandon, se oni volas demandi: "Ĉu vi vidas tion?" anstataŭ "Vi vidas tion, ĉu ne?".

(Redaktita)

Comment: Fakte, "Ĉu vi ne vidas tion?" (negativa demando) [estas evitinda](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/demandoj_respondoj/respondvortoj.html#i-4zl).

Comment: Ne nepre. La rekomendata maniero estas respondi per ripeti la verbon: Ĉu vi ne vidas tion? -- Jes, mi vidas / Ne, mi ne vidas.

Comment: :) Jes. Mi celis ke la negativa demando estas evitinda. Se iu tion tamen faras, vi pravas, la plej bona respondo estas ja tiu, kiun vi menciis. Tion ne igas la demandon malpli evitinda ;), ĉar, se eblas, prefere oni ne transdonu la respondecon pri unusenca komunikado al la alia.

Comment: Tiu paĝo de PMEG ne malrekomendas neajn demandojn, ĉu ne? Ĝi diras ke ili estas bezonataj por nuanco. “Iuj opinias, ke oni evitu negativajn demandojn, sed negativaj demandoj estas bezonataj por esprimi specialajn nuancojn. La lingvo malriĉiĝus, se oni ne povus uzi tiajn demandojn.”

Comment: En mia loko neaj demandoj estas tre kutimaj. Ekz. Mi alvenas al mia laborejo kaj demandas mian kolegon: Ĉu vi ne kuiris kafon? La ideo estas, ke ne gravas, se mia kolego ne ankoraŭ kuiris. Sed mi komprenas, ke temas pri loka kutimo.

Sed mi rigardas tiajn finodemandojn "…ĉu/…ĉu ne" strangaj.